# Mathematical description of random noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, noise

I am trying to mathematically model the noise affecting a certain physical quantity, say $X(t)$. Then, the noisy quantity would be $X'(t)$ which differs by some small value $\delta$ from the ideal quantity.

My question is, **what is the correct way to mathematically describe the noise?** Would it be something like
$$
X'(t)=X(t)+\delta(t)
$$
or
$$
X'(t)=X(t)\left[1+\delta(t)\right]
$$
Or maybe it's something compeletely different? And **I would like an explanation to help me comprehend and justify the choice**.

Comment: For additive noise, which is the usual one, it would be the first expression.

Comment: "additive" noise? Does this imply the existence of classification of noise by the mathematical description? Do you mind elaborating this for me please?

Comment: Well you can also have multiplicative noise. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_noise

Comment: There is no one way to mathematically describe noise. The "best" model (if such a thing even exists) depends on the situation and is built out of some combination of knowledge of how the detector works, experience, intuition, and tractability. Further, any analytically tractable model of noise is inevitably going to be approximate; you will either need to argue/show that the approximation is good, or (more likely) find ways to deal with "non ideal" features in the data that you can't model analytically.

Comment: Having said that a common assumption is to write $X' = X + \delta X$ and assume $\delta X$ is a [stationary, Gaussian random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_noise). But you can't *mathematically prove* this is the "right" model. It's just a tractable model that's useful in some situations.